# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. Tensorflow Chatbot

Tags: python, tensorflow, dll, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

I have an error saying `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`  I got this error when I was running main.py in this Github repository, https://github.com/llSourcell/chatbot_tutorial.  I downloaded all the things needed.  The following picture is the error.[image: The error]

Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the error, something to do with prerequisites I needed.  I deleted python, and reinstalled it, then installed tensorflow, and it worked.